# Compare strings for different values

Tags: vb.net, logic

I have 2 strings as:

STRING 1:
@serial1@code1@**true**@serial2@code2@false@serial3@code3@**true**

STRING 2:
@serial1@code1@**false**@serial2@code2@false@serial3@code3@**false**

what i need is information(serial1,code1,true/false) for the group for which it is changed. Like in above example i want data only for (serial1,code1,t/f) and (serial3,code3,t/f)

STRING1 is loaded on page_load and STRING2 will be loaded after click of save button. So i want to hit the database for only those values which are changed not for all the values.

Please suggest some suitable logic.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: ***Before suggesting*** `some suitable logic` can you please show us **what you have tried and where you are stuck**. We help other's with programming issues and questions, not a code writing site. On another note, you could create a class to hold your properties and create a method to go through and parse out the data you would need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use String.Split() to turn your string into a String Array, and then evaluate the array items.

Example:
    strOriginal() = string1.Split("@")
    strChanged() = string2.Split("@")

```
' Assuming both strings had the same number of elements...
For i as Integer = 0 to strOriginal.Length - 1
    If strOriginal(i) <> strChanged(i) Then
        ' Your DB write logic here...
    End If
Next
```